# Re-positioning Created Div's Using JS

Tags: javascript, html, position

So I created a DIV and tried to re-position it with this code:

```
var element = document.createElement("div")

element.id = "botinfo"

document.body.appendChild(element)

div = document.getElementById("botinfo")

div.style.position = "absolute"

div.style.top = 100
```

I create it fine and all but when I try re-position it nothing happens. I run

```
div.style.top = 100
```

Again at the console but still nothing. What's wrong?

Comment: Do you have any error at console? is div is holding the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting 100px instead.

```
div.style.top = "100px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, so easy, use this function look:

```
function RePosition(a,b,c) {
    a = document.getElementById(a);
    a.style.position = c;
    a.style.top = b+'px';
    return a;
}
```

how to use?, look:

```
RePosition('botinfo',x,'absolute'); //replace x with the number of the you new position
```

good, luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the unit as well when specifying the offset.
For example:

```
div.style.top = "100px"
div.style.top = "50%"
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Hope this helps.